# (android) Hidng actionbar/toolbar smoothly?

Tags: android

I'm making and publishing a web application which contains android web view. At enhancing my app, I tried to implement that when user scrolls web view, action bar disappears. I wrote some code with some libraries which can detect user's scrolling actions, and made it works.
But, It doesn't work smoothly. I had looked for answer, I couldn't find.. I captured how it works and comparing with default browser. [Youtube Link : https://youtu.be/rtgB0FSP8ek ]

What I did,

```
        // When scrolling
        public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == ScrollState.UP) {
                if(actionbar.isShowing()) actionbar.hide();
            } else if (scrollState == ScrollState.DOWN) {
                if(!actionbar.isShowing())actionbar.show();
            }
        }
```

and In my Activity Theme, I added this,

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

and in my Web view Layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        .....
```

Happy New Year!

Comment: Look in CollapseToolbarLayout. This is your saver.

Comment: @SergeyShustikov Thank you for your comment sir!. You mean if i change my root layout, that can be solved?? Actually, I don't know about CollapseToolBarLayout.

Comment: @Sergey is right...CollapsingToolbarLayout is your answer...tutorials are easily searchable on google

Comment: Yeap. Look at some of one example which are million in google.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar show/hide, does not have any animation, so you should add your animation to the toolbar to have a smooth show/hide transition.

```
void hideActionBar(){
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null && ab.isShowing()) {
        if(toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.animate().translationY(-212).alpha(0).setDuration(600L)
                    .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            ab.hide();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                        }
                    }).start();
        } else {
            ab.hide();
        }
    }
}

void showActionBar(){
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null && !ab.isShowing()) {
        ab.show();
        if(toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1).setDuration(600L).start();
        }
    }
}
```